# Updating object member variable from another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, scheduled-tasks

I have a requirement to refresh a member variable before it's expiry. I have opted to do it from another Thread which is spawned from a periodic ScheduledExecutorService Task. My aim is to refresh a connection object here before it's expiry which happens after a fixed time say about 2hours when the server would close it and there could be some potential data loss.
My code is something like the below

```
class Main {

    static ScheduledExecutorService clientReconnectPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

    Client client;

    Main() {
        clientReconnectPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            reconnectClient();
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }

    void reconnectClient() {

        Client newClient = initClient();
        if (newClient != null) {
            cleanupOldClient();
            client = newClient;
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to know whether it's a good practice to overwrite a member variable from another Thread like the above and if there are any cleaner alternatives to this.

Comment: If you are replacing the old `Client` object with a new one, why do any cleanup on the old one? Your question is not clear. Furthermore, the topic of updating objects across threads has been handled many many times already on Stack Overflow. Edit your Question to indicate how none of the existing Questions & Answers address your issue.

Comment: I am doing the cleanup here as it has a network callback attached and even though I replace the reference the object might not be GC'ed. So I will 'close()' the old object. I couldn't find any question where the reference is outright replaced. Appreciate if you could link me to one.

Comment: And part of question is if there's a better way to do this.